# How to directly access module's constant in HTML on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use several constants directly in html (and few times in controllers).

For example, this is main app module:

```
angular.module('website', [])
.constant('ROUTES', (function () {
    return {
        SIGN_IN: '/sign/in'
  }
})())
.config([..., 'ROUTES', function(..., ROUTES {
    $routeProvider.when(ROUTES.SIGN_IN, {templateUrl: 'pages/sign_in.html', controller:     'SignInController'});
}]);
```

So this is clear, how to use constants from controllers.

But how can I do something like this:

```
<html ng-app="website"> 
<body>
<a href="{{ROUTES.SIGN_IN}}">Sign in</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The point is to keep all routes in one place. 
So, can i do this, or may be i choosed wrong way?

Comment: just add ROUTES to the $scope in SignInController

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's actualy what i need.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

IMHO the better way to do this is use the [$rootScope](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.$rootScope)
In html every scope inherits from the $rootScope, so if a variable isn't present in the current scope angular use the one declared in $rootScope.

A good way is to initialize this in the *run* "phase"

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .run(function ($rootScope) {
      $rootScope.ROUTES = ROUTES
   });
```

Comment: I think this should be a concept that everyone attempts to understand before they go writing any controllers.  I don't know how many times i've worked on a controller with scope and rootscope loaded into it.

Comment: Keep in mind that the value defined in `$rootScope` will not be accessible directly in directives with isolated scopes. In such cases you can get this value with `$root.ROUTES` in the view.

Answer (score 19):

Slightly similar to other answers but IMO cleaner:

```
angular.module('website')
    .constant("ROUTES", {
        SIGN_IN: "/sign/in"
    })
    .run(function ($rootScope, ROUTES) {
        $rootScope.ROUTES = ROUTES;
    });
```

And:

```
<a href="{{ROUTES.SIGN_IN}}">Sign in</a>
```

HTH

Comment: This is a good approach. Keeps the code running while maintaining separation from data.

Answer (score 16):

I also like the $rootScope approach, but I have, in some situations used a filter.

As a simplified example, suppose there is a constant CONFIG defined somewhere as an object with a property called BuildVersion. You could create a filter something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .filter('interpolate', ['CONFIG', function (CONFIG) {
      return function (text) {
          return String(text).replace(/\%VERSION\%/mg, CONFIG.BuildVersion);
      };  
  }]);
```

And in the HTML:

```
<html ng-app="website"> 
    <body>
        <div>{{'%VERSION%' | interpolate}}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

or

```
<html ng-app="website"> 
    <body>
        <div>{{'bla bla bla %VERSION%.' | interpolate}}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I almost used this because it was familiar, and it's a good answer, but I do think the accepted answer is better overall. Upvoted both.

Answer (score 1):

Also we can use helper, similar to ROR.

https://gist.github.com/merqlove/491023bcdd2145eef169#file-readme-md