# How to get value of nested constants in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash, angularjs-filter, angular-constant

I've been trying to get the value of the nested constants inside the angular constants using angular filter. But I can't find an efficient way to get the values. I'm allowed to use lodash "^2.4.1" and i tried using _.pick but still i could only access the root level constants and not the nested ones.

```
//consider this
angular.module('myApp',[])

.constants('appConstants', {
    CONS1: 'root',
    CONS2: {
          NEST1: 'nested cons1',
          NEST2: 'nested cons2',
    }
)
.filter(getConstants, function  () {
    return function  (input) {
        var value =  appConstants[input];
        if (! value) {
            var keys = input.split('.');
            value =  appConstants;
            angular.forEach(keys, function(key, index) {
                value = value[key];
            });
        }
        return value;
    }
});

//where as
appConstants[CONS1]; //works
appConstants[CONS2.NEST1]; // return undefined
//in lodash
_.pick(appConstants, 'CONS2.NEST1'); // returns empty object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have the option of using the [Angular `$parse` function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse). I think this will work if you provide it with your root constant object as the context parameter.

That might look something like:

```
$parse(input)(appConstants)
```

Comment: Please do not approve suggested edits that changes the code. See [When should I make edits to code?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/1218980)

Comment: OK, fine, but that has nothing to do with my answer.

Comment: Yeah but that's the only way to notify you, SO doesn't have comments on suggested edit review. Good answer by the way!

Comment: @AmyBlankenship Thank you, This is THE most efficient approach.

Answer (score 2):

## Using AngularJS constants

An [AngularJS constant](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant) is just the value (here an object) it is defined to be.

```
{
    CONS1: 'root',
    CONS2: {
          NEST1: 'nested cons1',
          NEST2: 'nested cons2',
    }
}
```

To get `NEST1`, use the usual [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), the dot notation `appConstants.CONS1.NEST1` or the bracket notation `appConstants["CONS1"]["NEST1"]`.

---

## Accessing the constants in the HTML template

The simplest way is just to add the constant object into the `$rootScope`.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .constants('appConstants', {
        CONS1: 'root',
        CONS2: {
            NEST1: 'nested cons1',
            NEST2: 'nested cons2',
        }
    })
    .run(function($rootScope, appConstants) {
        $rootScope.CONSTANTS = appConstants;
    });
```

And in any template, just use `CONSTANTS` as an object.

```
<span>{{ CONSTANTS.CONS2.NEST1 }}</span>
```

Source: [Can I directly access module constant from HTML under AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505138/can-i-directly-access-module-constant-from-html-under-angularjs)

---

## Using Lodash

If you really want to use lodash, use the [`_.get` function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get) which enables complex path to resolve to the right nested object.

```
_.get(appConstants, "CONS1.NEST1");
```

So a filter could be as simple as:

```
.filter("const", function() {
    return function(input) {
        return _.get(appConstants, input);
    };
});
```

Pass a string path to the filter to get a value.

```
{{ "CONS2.NEST1" | const }}
```

---

## Built-in alternative to Lodash

[Amy Blankenship presents Angular's `$parse`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42281855/1218980) in her answer which, in my opinion, is a better approach than Lodash in this case.

---

> I can't use `_.get` because I'm allowed to use the older version of [lodash 2.4.1](https://lodash.com/docs/2.4.2).

There are two options:

- Use the [stand-alone lodash package for `_.get`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.get)
- Make a simpler implementation

`_.get` is quite complex, but for our simple case, a simple string `split` on dots would probably do.

```
.filter("getConstants", function() {
    return function(input) {
        var obj = appConstants,
            path = input.split('.'),
            index = 0,
            length = path.length;

        while (obj != null && index < length) {
            obj = obj[path[index++]];
        }
        return obj;
    };
});
```

Comment: I can't use _.get because I'm allowed to use the older version of lodash 2.4.1. The problem is I could pass the object path as String from my view (html).  {{ CONS2.NEST1 | getConstant}} <- this won't work and gives me undefined when it reaches the filter. So I am passing it to filter as -> {{' CONS2.NEST1' | getConstant}}

Comment: @BalajeeKs I added a section related to lodash 2.4.1.

Comment: @BalajeeKs please do not edit the code inside other's post. The code works as-is and already takes care of root level properties. See [When should I make edits to code?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/1218980)

Comment: @BalajeeKs I added a better approach using the `$rootScope` that you might want to try out.

Comment: I've previously used $rootscope throughout the application but I was advised not to use it. Which is why I've thought of creating a filter. I find AmyBlankenship 's solution to be perfect approach rather than writing my own function.

Comment: @BalajeeKs While I agree that polluting the `$rootScope` is not a good idea, our case here is one of the reason to use it. It's THE most efficient way. Using `$parse` for a filter is better than using Lodash, but not better than [exposing the constants in the `$rootScope` like most seems to agree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505138/can-i-directly-access-module-constant-from-html-under-angularjs).

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten closing brace ( '}' ) in the constant declaration.

Maybe try this :

```
.constants('appConstants', {
    CONS1: 'root',
    CONS2: {
          NEST1: 'nested cons1',
          NEST2: 'nested cons2',
    }
})
```

Comment: Sorry Jermy, I missed a bracket : }  in this example. I had it right in my code.